# How to identify the operation type(insert,update,delete) in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

We are using the following trigger in SQL Server to maintain the history now I need to identify the operations just like insert,update or delete. I found some information [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965521/oracle-and-triggers-inserted-updated-deleted) but it doesn't works with the SQL Server.

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_guest_details ON [PMS].[GSDTLTBL] 
FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @SRLNUB1 INT;
    DECLARE @UPDFLG1 DECIMAL(3,0);

    SELECT @SRLNUB1 = I.SRLNUB FROM inserted I;
    SELECT @UPDFLG1 = I.UPDFLG FROM inserted I;   

    BEGIN
       /* Here I need to identify the operation and insert the operation type in the GUEST_ADT 3rd field */
       insert into dbo.GUEST_ADT values(@SRLNUB1,@UPDFLG1,?);

       PRINT 'BEFORE INSERT trigger fired.'
    END;
GO
```

But here I need to identify the operation and want to insert operation type accordingly.

Here I don't want to create three trigger for every operations

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ... FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Actually my application works only with the one row at a time. If I will update then it will updates only one row at a time(Its my primary requirement of the app.) though the multiple row issue will never deny or stop me ever. If identifying the operation type is possible then please help me.

Comment: I think you have to visit [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965521/oracle-and-triggers-inserted-updated-deleted) which will tell you it's possible.

Comment: At least put in a test for more than one row if anyone ever do maintenance on the table outside your app.

Comment: Dear @adrianm you should have to check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965521/oracle-and-triggers-inserted-updated-deleted) too. If its possible with them then why not for me ?

Comment: We can check it with this  `IF DELETING THEN` , `IF INSERTING THEN` and `IF UPDATING THEN` in other servers then can't we use it in SQL-SERVER.?

Comment: Because the link is for **Oracle**. `FOR EACH ROW` is not availble in **Sql-Server**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server trigger on insert,delete & update on table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217484/sql-server-trigger-on-insert-delete-update-on-table)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For Inserted : Rows are in inserted only.
For Updated: Rows are in inserted and deleted.
For Deleted: Rows are in deleted only.

```
DECLARE @event_type varchar(42)
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    SELECT @event_type = 'update'
ELSE
    SELECT @event_type = 'insert'
ELSE
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    SELECT @event_type = 'delete'
  ELSE
    --no rows affected - cannot determine event
    SELECT @event_type = 'unknown'
```

Comment: Dear @Mikhail Timofeev SQL Says `SELECT * FROM inserted` Invalid Object name `inserted` same in `deleted` I think this is not working in SQL Server.

Comment: inserted and deleted are the part of sql server triggers, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information. the code i've postet should be inserted in your trigger, it can not work outside of trigger.

Comment: Wow nice one can you elaborate it and post it as an answer ? I will choose as an answer if it will works well.

Comment: you have to do something by youself

Comment: Please elaborate it for better quality of answer I am just going to approve your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: Actually I am getting error at `inserted` Invalid Object Name `inserted`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simplified version of Mikhail's answer that uses a [searched CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @Operation varchar(7) = 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) 
        THEN 'Update'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) 
        THEN 'Insert'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
        THEN 'Delete'
    ELSE 
        NULL --Unknown
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get multiple rows at once we do it as follows.

```
INSERT INTO Log_Table
(
    LogDate
    ,LogAction
    -- your field list here
    ,Field0
    -- Example : Tracking new and old value for a specific field
    -- Make sure that the [Field1_Old] is nullable or has a default value
    ,Field1,Field1_Old
)
SELECT 
    LogDate=GETDATE() 
    ,LogAction = CASE WHEN d.[PK_Field] IS NULL THEN 'I' ELSE 'U' END           
    ,i.Field0
    ,i.Field1, d.Field1
FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN deleted d on i.[PK_Field]=d.[PK_Field]
WHERE i.[PK_Field] IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO Log_Table
(
    LogDate
    ,LogAction
    -- your field list here
    ,Field0
    -- Example : Tracking new and old value for a specific field
    -- Make sure that the [Field1_Old] is nullable or has a default value
    ,Field1,Field1_Old
)
SELECT 
    LogDate=GETDATE() 
    ,LogAction = 'D'
    ,d.Field0
    ,d.Field1, NULL
FROM deleted d 
    LEFT JOIN inserted i on i.[PK_Field]=d.[PK_Field]
WHERE i.[PK_Field] IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create trigger my_trigger on my_table
after update , delete , insert
as
declare @inserting bit
declare @deleting  bit
declare @updating  bit = 0

select @inserting = coalesce (max(1),0) where exists (select 1 from inserted)
select @deleting  = coalesce (max(1),0) where exists (select 1 from deleted )
select @inserting = 0
     , @deleting = 0
     , @updating = 1
  where @inserting = 1 and @deleting = 1
print   'Inserting = ' + ltrim (@inserting)
    + ', Deleting = '  + ltrim (@deleting)
    + ', Updating = '  + ltrim (@updating)
```

If all three are zero, there are no rows affected and I think there is no way to tell whether it is an update/delete/insert.